# Python pg8000 1.9.4 parameterized statement error not in pg8000 1.08

Tags: python, postgresql

I hope someone can help me because I've been struggling with this problem for 2 days now...

Using the latest pg8000 driver (1.9.4) i prepare a statement with parameters and when try to execute it get this error :

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'SELECT'
```

I found out that using the pg8000 driver (1.08) i didn't had this error (notice it when i went back to my dev environement)

Here is my code :

```
self._dbConnection = dbapi.connect(host=self.host,
                                   user=self.user,
                                   password=self.pwd ,
                                   database=self.name,
                                   port=self.port)

stmt = "SELECT lb FROM vig.departement WHERE id = %s"
cursor = self.dbConnection.cursor()
cursor.execute(stmt, [1])
row = cursor.fetchone()
cursor.close()
```

I don't see what am doing wrong or if am missing something between pg8000 1.08 and 1.9.4.

More info just in case : My data base version is PostgreSQL 8.3.8 (from `psql --version`) which is hosted by a *Cent0S 5.3* and my client executing the python script is on a *Cent0S 6.3*.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm a contributor to pg8000, and the problem is that pg8000 doesn't support PostgreSQL 8.3. In fact, according to http://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/ support for Postgres 8.3 in general ended in February 2013.

Comment: This explains stuff... So i should stick to pg8000 1.08 if i want to handle a 8.3 postgresql databases? 
Thanks for the answer!